# Sharing GIFs with iOS app from Android app

Tags: android, ios, gif

Has anyone one worked on attaching GIFs in apps? Something similar to WhatsApp or Skype.

When I try to get the content uri from the below code -

```
final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback = new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat info, int flags, Bundle opts) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1 && (flags & InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                try {
                    info.requestPermission();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false; // return false if failed
                }
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "Content URI " + info.getContentUri());
            return true;  // return true if succeeded
        }
    };
    return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, info, callback);
}
```

This is what the content URI looks like, which works fine when passed to Glide.

`Content URI (Swift keyboard) -> content://com.touchtype.swiftkey.fileprovider/share_images/Bi7V7tixYcLzbNgEJhE_NaXQ5eE.gif`

`Content URI(Gboard) -> content://com.google.android.inputmethod.latin.inputcontent/inputContent?fileName=%2Fdata%2Fuser_de%2F0%2Fcom.google.android.inputmethod.latin%2Ffiles%2Fgif69727604103223767740&packageName=com.testsdk&mimeType=image%2Fgif`

But when same is passed to iOS app, then it will not work.

Can you please guide me in correct direction?
What needs to be sent to iOS app, so that same selected GIF can be shown in iOS app as well?

**EDIT - I think I should use getLinkUri() instead of getContentUri().
Is it correct approach?**

**URI https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OGC.5e1a1b1d71e12b32cc7bfac93fbb7d1f&pid=Api&rurl=https%3a%2f%2fmedia.giphy.com%2fmedia%2fVe20ojrMWiTo4%2f200.gif&ehk=iHJHy%2fFSR7s2nIoEXxTIrUAWWuGBnz%2fecKwkM8Hm2ac%3d**

Comment: The GIF itself should be sent. The iOS app won't be able to resolve the Android content URL.

Comment: @CoderCharmander Can you please elaborate 'GIF itself should be sent'? What exactly needs to be sent here?

Do I have to save the gif internally and share that file ?

Comment: That would be a solution.